# making a trigger where clause rely on 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, nested

I have an issue with this trigger I am trying to make. It is for a college project so it needs to be done with a trigger!

I have 3 tables which involve the trigger. Customer_order, product_customer_order, and product_branch_stock (their contents and purpose are listed below). I've also included the code I am using, although, I've tried so many different variations of it which haven't worked, this is the latest one.

I can get the trigger working to reduce stock on the product_branch_stock table according to just the branch_id on the customer_order insert, but it can't account for the product_id, which is on another table. So, I'm also really wondering how I can bring that other table into the trigger?

The design may not be the best, but bare in mind I'm only about 6 weeks into sql at the moment and I've still a lot to learn! So, any help you could give, would be super appreciated! My project is due on Friday!

EDIT: I have added tables with relevant columns and sample rows below

This trigger I'm trying to make (Possibly a nested trigger)
should do the following when a row is inserted into customer_order table

- insert row (any values) in product_customer_order
- update the product_branch_stock stock column by taking away from it
  the quantity    on the customer_order table
- Only do this on rows WHERE the new branch_id (from the insert
  on customer order) is equal to the branch_id on
  product_branch_stock AND where the new product_id (from     the
  triggered insert on product_customer_order) is equal to the
  product_id on the product_branch_stock.
- customer_order (customer_order_id,order_time, order_date,username,
  branch_id)
- product_customer_order( customer_order_id, product_id,
  quantity,) *(This is an intermediary between product and
  customer_order table, as there was a many to many relationship).*
- product_branch_stock (product_id, branch_id, stock) *This is a table which I created in an attempt to be able to monitor stock of every product in every individual branch)*

```
    create schema test;
    use test;
    
    CREATE TABLE customer_order (
    customer_order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,    # foreign key
    branch_id INT NOT NULL,           # foreign key
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_order_id)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO customer_order (customer_order_id, username, branch_id)
    VALUES  ('1','Paddytheboi101', 2 );
    
    INSERT INTO customer_order (customer_order_id, username, branch_id)
    VALUES  ('2','LuCkYmIkE', 1 );  
    
    INSERT INTO customer_order (customer_order_id, username, branch_id)
    VALUES  ('3','DutchDefence',  1 );
    
    
    
    #intermediary table due to many to many relationship - order can have #multiple products, product can be on multiple orders
    
    CREATE TABLE product_customer_order (
    customer_order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # primary and foreign key
    product_id INT NOT NULL,   # primary and foreign key 
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_order_id, product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_order_id) REFERENCES customer_order (customer_order_id)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO product_customer_order (customer_order_id, product_id, quantity)
    VALUES ('1', '8', '1');
    
    INSERT INTO product_customer_order (customer_order_id, product_id, quantity)
    VALUES ('2', '21', '4');
    
    INSERT INTO product_customer_order (customer_order_id, product_id, quantity)
    VALUES ('3', '32', '3');
    
    
    CREATE TABLE product_branch_stock (
    product_id INT NOT NULL,   # foreign key
    branch_id INT NOT NULL,    # foreign key
    stock INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (branch_id, product_id)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO product_branch_stock (product_id, branch_id, stock)
    VALUES (8,2,10);
    INSERT INTO product_branch_stock (product_id, branch_id, stock)
    VALUES (21,1,10);
    INSERT INTO product_branch_stock (product_id, branch_id, stock)
    VALUES (32,1,10);
```

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS X;
CALL DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER X
AFTER INSERT ON customer_order
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO product_customer_order (product_id, quantity)
VALUES (7, 2);

UPDATE product_branch_stock AS pbs
SET pbs.stock = pbs.stock - new.product_customer_order.quantity
WHERE new.branch_id = pbs.branch_id AND
product_customer_order.product_id = pbs.product_id;

END//
```

Comment: You can select from another table within a trigger and fetch the results into a cursor or other variables.

Comment: Please provide: CREATE TABLE for all 3 tables (the columns unrelated to the process and all non-unique indices except needed for FKs between these tables may be skipped); some example data for these tables (3-5 rows enough) as INSERT INTO; the query which inserts data into `customer_order` (which initializes the process) and desired final tables data (as formatted table-type text). Try to make all number values unique (i.e. each value may be obtained from initial values by one way only if possible).

Comment: @Akina Firstly many thanks for looking at my problem! I have made create table commands with some dummy data as you requested. Should work fine, I tested it in a "test" schema in mysql. The dummy data is aligned in all tables, si they all have matching foreign keys etc. I left out most of the foreign key constaints (These are linked with other irrelevant tables also in my project, so when I copied and pasted it wouldn't let me update the child table without the parent table first, naturally.

Comment: Also I understand my code looks quite messy compared to the trigger code, it looks the same type of test as the comment/question text. Is there any way to change it so it looks like the trigger code? Like, where it's colored and everything? Sorry, complete beginner with stack overflow too.